# Не полностью загружается файл mp3

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь сделать загрузку mp3 файлов на сервер.
Есть вот такой код:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['doUpload']) { 
//проверяем загрузку файла на наличие ошибок
if($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] > 0)
{
//в зависимости от номера ошибки выводим соответствующее сообщение
//UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE - значение установленное в php.ini
//MAX_FILE_SIZE значение указанное в html-форме загрузки файла
switch ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'])
{
case 1: echo 'Размер файла превышает допустимое значение UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE'; break;
case 2: echo 'Размер файла превышает допустимое значение MAX_FILE_SIZE'; break;
case 3: echo 'Не удалось загрузить часть файла'; break;
case 4: echo 'Файл не был загружен'; break;
case 6: echo 'Отсутствует временная папка.'; break;
case 7: echo 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.'; break;
case 8: echo 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.'; break;
}
exit;
}

//проверяем MIME-тип файла
if($_FILES['uploadfile']['type'] != 'audio/mp3')
{
echo 'Вы пытаетесь загрузить не текстовый файл.';
exit;
}

//проверяем не является ли загружаемый файл php скриптом,
//при необходимости можете дописать нужные типы файлов
$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
foreach ($blacklist as $item)
{
if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']))
{
echo "Выбраный вами файл не являеться mp3 файлом.";
exit;
}
}

//папка для загрузки
$uploaddir = 'audioupload/';
//новое сгенерированное имя файла
$newFileName=date('YmdHis').rand(10,100).'.mp3';
//путь к файлу (папка.файл)
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$newFileName;

//загружаем файл move_uploaded_file
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Выбранный файл загружен.\n";
} else {
echo "Ошибка загрузки файла.\n"; 
}
//считываем содержания файла
$fp = fopen($uploadfile, 'r');
$contents = fread($fp, filesize ($uploadfile));
fclose($fp);

//чистим от php и html дескрипторов
$contents = strip_tags($contents);
$fp = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $contents);
fclose($fp);
}
?>


<form action="" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000000">
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" required><br />
    <input type="submit" name="doUpload" value="Загрузить">
    </form>
```

Этот код выполняет загрузку mp3 файлов на сервер, НО, например, файл весит 3мб, а загружает всего 80кб. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте загрузку без проверок сначала:

```
<?php
if (@$_REQUEST['doUpload']) { 
//проверяем загрузку файла на наличие ошибок
if($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] > 0)
{
//в зависимости от номера ошибки выводим соответствующее сообщение
//UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE - значение установленное в php.ini
//MAX_FILE_SIZE значение указанное в html-форме загрузки файла
switch ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error'])
{
case 1: echo 'Размер файла превышает допустимое значение     UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE'; break;
case 2: echo 'Размер файла превышает допустимое значение MAX_FILE_SIZE';     break;
case 3: echo 'Не удалось загрузить часть файла'; break;
case 4: echo 'Файл не был загружен'; break;
case 6: echo 'Отсутствует временная папка.'; break;
case 7: echo 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.'; break;
case 8: echo 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.'; break;
}
exit;
}
/*
//проверяем MIME-тип файла
if($_FILES['uploadfile']['type'] != 'audio/mp3')
{
echo 'Вы пытаетесь загрузить не текстовый файл.';
exit;
}
/
//проверяем не является ли загружаемый файл php скриптом,
//при необходимости можете дописать нужные типы файлов
$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
foreach ($blacklist as $item)
{
if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']))
{
echo "Выбраный вами файл не являеться mp3 файлом.";
exit;
}
}
*/
//папка для загрузки
$uploaddir = 'audioupload/';
//новое сгенерированное имя файла
//$newFileName=date('YmdHis').rand(10,100).'.mp3';

$newFileName=time().'.mp3';

//путь к файлу (папка.файл)
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$newFileName;

//загружаем файл move_uploaded_file
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Выбранный файл загружен.\n";
} else {
echo "Ошибка загрузки файла.\n"; 
}

?>


<form action="" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000000">-->
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" required><br />
<input type="submit" name="doUpload" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```